# Jquery ajax Function not bind return result

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 controller to return value to ajax function to do something in client side. unfortunately that return value not bind in to ajax method. please help me.

My ajax method;

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Service/Utility/GetcustomerAddressProofByCustomerId',
        data: { customerId: customerId },
        success: function (rtnResult) {
                 if (rtnResult.Result.lenght > 0) {
                  alert("ok");
                 }
                 else {
                  alert("no");
                 }
                }
      });
```

Controller Method;

```
 public ActionResult GetcustomerAddressProofByCustomerId(int customerId)
        {
            List<CustomerSecondaryID> items = db.CustomerSecondaryID.Where(a => a.customerId == customerId).ToList();

            return Json(items , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

please help me to do this.

Comment: Where is `dataType: 'json'` ?

Comment: just as a hint (which i use daily), you can write "console.log(rtnResult);" + any decent browser i'd suggest chrome, to see the format of the result, to assist with debugging your javascript.

Comment: yes. its json but it also going to alert("no")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo `lenght` also you can directly call `length` on rtnResult, since it is an array. Set `dataType:'json'` as you are returning `application/json` content type

```
 success: function (rtnResult) {
           if (rtnResult.length > 0) {
             alert("ok");
           },
 dataType:'json'
```